# Woocommerce blank screen variable product attribute image thumbnail

Tags: media, plugins

I am using woocommerce, I have setup a variable product. Under each attribute, when I try to add a thumbnail image by clicking on the Insert Into Post button for the Media Uploader dialog, the dialog box becomes empty without any content.

In the javascript console in Google Chrome, I get the following error:
post.php:1310 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this was fixed in WC 1.5.2 :)